# phpass Warning?

Tags: php, hash, passwords, phpass

I just implemented phpass into my websites register code and it seemed to work, but it gave me the following warning

```
Warning: is_readable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/dev/urandom) is not `within the allowed path(s): (/home/u997733154:/usr/lib/php:/tmp) in /home/u997733154/public_html/PasswordHash.php on line 51`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your php.ini file. There is a restriction in place by default concerning what files you can open.

See this link for more details : http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Comment: Can't find my php.ini, but I'm contacting my web host about that.  I'll accept your answer though because another person asked the same question and what you said is what worked for him.